# Проблема установки Scrot

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня возникла проблема с установкой `Scrot`,после того как я ввожу в консоль `sudo apt-get install scrot`, появляется следующее:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Пакет scrot недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «scrot» не найден кандидат на установку
```

Я пробовал

```
sudo apt clean

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

sudo apt-get install scrot
```

Но это не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** Я использую linux `Ubuntu 20.10`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно поможет один из пунктов:

1. Открыть приложение `Программы и обновления`, на вкладке `Программное обеспечение Ubuntu` поставить галочки на всех пунктах. Система должна предложить обновить список пакетов.
2. Попробовать сделать `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zerkalica/main`, затем `sudo apt-get update`. Попробовать установить `Scrot`.
3. Использовать установщик `deb`, скачанный с [сайта](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=scrot&searchon=names&suite=groovy&section=all) `Ubuntu`.
4. [Источник и более подробное руководство.](https://losst.ru/oshibka-package-has-no-installation-candidate)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, третий пункт помог!